# Issue Signing in to use GitHub Copilot

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-copilot

After attempting to sign into GitHub Copilot in VS Code a prompt pops up "The extension 'GitHub Copilot' wants to sign in using GitHub" and it gives me the option "`Allow`" or "`Cancel`".

After allowing another prompts states "`Allow an extension to open this URI?`".
After clicking "`Open`" an error message says

```
GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. 
Extension activation failed: "network error".
```

[image: error messages]

On occasion the actual approval page pops up and I approve permissions, then get a popup in vs studio, click open then it fails on "`Network Error`"

How do I go about resolving this issue?

I tried the above. Was expecting to be signed into GitHub copilot after approval.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the issue persists.

There was a recent [incident with Copilot](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/tyk95n0z3pql)

> We see authentication failures for a small percentage of users.
> We are investigating the root cause and will update as we learn more.

It is resolved, but you might still see some side-effect.

Comment: Could definitely be an issue with copilot, but it appears that I am also having issues using the settings sync and just GitHub authentication in general. So not 100% sure.